# How can I order products by price

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

How can I order products by price from the route in laravel?
how to tag it to the end of the route?
this is the rout

> Route::get('shop/{category_url}?sort=ASC','SortController@sortByASC');

Answer (score 1):

You need not to add that in the route, you just need to pass it to the url e.g

```
Route::get('shop/{category}', 'SomeController@someFunction');
```

Now in your controller function :

```
public function someFunction($category, Request $request)
{

     $query = Model::query();
     if($request->sort)
      {
        $query = $query->orderBy('price', $request->sort);
      }
   $query = $query->get();
}
```

from your view build this url

```
<a href="/shop/{{$category}}?sort=ASC">Sort product ascending</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, I want them to be able  from the page of category to click on "low to high" and "high to low" and then the order of the products will change, right now it's automtically arange them by low to high

Comment: yes it will work if you want to change it that way, but if you are displaying data in table format then use dataTables https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4.html

Comment: Can u show me how can I change the function to work for both> ASC and DESC

Comment: I tried to wrote that linke u said in the view:                                                              <a href="/shop/{{$category}}?sort=ASC">Sort product ascending</a>               it says                                                                                                               htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View:

Comment: make sure $category is a string and not an array

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('shop/{category_url}','SortController@sort');
```

Let's assume that your link looks like. .../shop/category?sort=ASC. You can get the value of get paramethers in your controller:

```
class SortController extends MainController{
    public function sortByASC($category, Request $request)
    {
        if ($category1 = Categorie::where('url', '=', $category)->first()) {
            $sort = $request->get('sort', 'asc');
            $products = Product::where('categorie_id', $category1->getAttribute('id'))->orderBy('price', $sort)->get();
            $sort = $sort == 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc'; // to use in sort link
            return view('content.sort', compact('products', 'sort'));
        }
    }
}
```

In your content/sort.blade.php file:

```
<!-- When the link is clicked orders are sorted ascending by default. When it is clicked again after page reload orders are sorted descending and it goes so on -->
<a href=".../shop/{{category_url}}?sort={{$sort}}">Sort {{$sort === 'asc' ? 'ascending' : 'descending'}}</a>
```

Comment: Can u show me how to combine this in my controller?                 class SortController extends MainController{
    
 
 public function sortByASC( $category,Request $request )

{
 
     if ($category1=Categorie::where('url','=', $category)->first()){
     
     
    $sort = $request->get('sort', 'asc');
  
$products = Product::where('categorie_id', $category1->getAttribute(
'id'))->orderBy('price', $sort)->get();

  return view('content.sort')->with('products', $products) ;

}

Comment: It works but after the page sort.blade is openning and from there I want to click again "low to high" or "high to low" it sais                                                       Undefined variable: category (View: C:\xampp5\htdocs\myshop\resources\views\content\sort.blade.php)

Comment: after I click the <a href=".../shop/{{category_url}}?sort={{$sort}}"> it sais       Use of undefined constant category_url - assumed 'category_url'

Comment: I used category_url as an example. The value of category_url depends on the logic of your app. Just replace category_url with the url of category that you want to retrieve.

Comment: I changed it to this:          
<a href="{{ url('shop/'.$category['url'])}}?sort={{$sort}}">Sort {{$sort === 'asc' ? 'ascending' : 'descending'}}</a>                                                         (the category url is dynamic).                                                                            now it sais:  Undefined variable: sort (View:

Comment: Please I don't understand why sort is undefined